# How do I go about comparing values of 2 lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two python files consisting of the following:

File 1

```
('9', '154331672')
['0.165435473']
('8', '100949929')
['0.493410385']
('9', '120747803')
['0.969364472']
('1', '12152579')
['0.669831913']
```

File 2

```
('8', '158116110')
['0.00509']
('6', '44338625')
['0.00525']
('3', '127518469')
['2.56E-05']
('9', '141754441')
['0.00585']
('4', '144499616')
['0.00356']
('3', '181007619')
['0.00648']
```

The values are the numbers located in brackets. What I am trying to achieve is to the extent of:

```
if ((File1_Values - File2_Values) < 10000):
    count +=1
```

Excuse me if that makes no sense, I am actually asking for help in developing the code.

My expected output would be the count. Because both lists are very long, if I were to take a random selection of values from File1_Values and compared them to File2_Values how many of those values would be less than 10,000.

For the first time I run the loop perhaps I may get:

```
1500
```

Second time:

```
9900
```

Comment: could you provide the expected output

Comment: So you are interested in finding out how many of e.i. `['0.165435473']` this type of data each file contains?

Comment: you want to subtract `'154331672'` and `158116110` and see if they are greater then 10,000 and increase counter if so and you want to check only the second value of the tuple and you don want to check the list am I right

Comment: Do the two files have the same number of elements? Are you trying to find the correspondence that minimizes the number of differences bigger than 10000? If this is the case then the problem contains as special case an instance of the set cover NP-complete problem... (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Comment: Yes simply in both lists, I only want to compare the values of the tuples ( the numbers located in the brackets). To clarify, File2 is my main list and I want to compare random values from File1 (which is an enormous list) to those in File2. And count how many of those values are less than 10,000 @VigneshKalai

Comment: No both files do not contain the same number of elements. File2 is my main list and I am pulling random elements from File1 (an enormous list) , creating a smaller list, and would simply like to now compare the smaller list (File1) to my main list (File2). @6502

Comment: You want to do this randomly  check file 1 and 2 how many lines you want to check and does the pattern looks like this that is every first line is tuple and second line will be list